# alternative to forticlient for IPSec vpn?

Tags: vpn, firewall

our company has a fortigate firewall and we forticlient software. the software has many function like antivirus, parental contro, vpn etc. but we only use it for the vpn purpose.

my question is there any other alternative IPSec vpn client which is compatible to fortigate?

We use a preshared key, to connect the vpn

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Shrewsoft VPN Client](https://www.shrew.net/software) is an alternative to FortiClient.

FortiNet has a KB entry. There they have a zipped PDF with instructions. (Why they had to ZIP the PDF, I have no idea.): 
[Fortinet KB #FD33774: *Technical Note : How to configure Windows version of Shrew Soft IPSec VPN tunnel with a FortiGate*](http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD33774) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/yeV2k).)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.